# How to print to the next line in a .txt file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
'''def get_us_value(fp):
    '''Insert docstring here.'''
    print()
    print(fp.readline())
    for x in fp:
        for y in x.split():
            if y == 'States':'''
```

I would like to print the next line after states in order to get the number associated with United States but I am currently stuck on how to print the next line after states.
This is the .txt file

```
United
States
91.9
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? You clearly know how to print, you know how to use loops, so where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not pick this solution as I don't know whether you can use regex or not but you can use regex to get the matching result.
I don't know what the use case actually is but assuming you only have those lines in a text file, the regex `States\n(.*)` should match the whole line after the keyword `States`.

```py
import re

print(re.findall(r"States\n(.*)", fp.read())[0])
```

**Output:**

```
91.9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use \n.

For example: if you do print(“foo \nbar”) foo is line one, bar is line two.

Look at this, it can be helpful:
https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/cmdlinetips.com/2012/09/three-ways-to-write-text-to-a-file-in-python/amp/

Comment: Is the issue really printing on multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `next` function on the file object to obtain the next line:

```
for x in fp:
    if 'States' in x.split():
        print(next(fp), end='')
```